# How to download HTML encoded with PHP/JavaScript content using WGET or Perl

Tags: php, html, perl, unix, wget

I have a URL which I want to download and parse:

```
http://diana.cslab.ece.ntua.gr/micro-CDS/index.php?r=search/results_mature&mir=hsa-miR-3131&kwd=MIMAT0014996
```

The problem is when I download with unix `wget` the following way:

```
$ wget [the above url]
```

It gave me the content which is different with those I saw over the browser (namely, the list of genes was not there).

What's the right way to do it programatically?

Comment: It works for me. Are you quoting the url? "http...996"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#/usr/bin/perl

use WWW::Mechanize;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $url = "http://diana.cslab.ece.ntua.gr/micro-CDS/index.php?r=search/results_mature&mir=hsa-miR-3131&kwd=MIMAT0014996";

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$mech->agent_alias("Windows IE 6");

$mech->get($url);
#now you have access to the HTML code via $mech->content();
```

To process HTML code I'm strongly recommend to `use HTML::TreeBuilder::XPath` (or other HTML parsing module)

Answer (score 1):

I've just tested using PHP and its pulling it with the genes list just fine

```
<?php
echo file_get_contents('http://diana.cslab.ece.ntua.gr/micro-CDS/index.php?r=search/results_mature&mir=hsa-miR-3131&kwd=MIMAT0014996');
?>
```

do you have access to PHP